# Vuejs2 update Vue.prototype global object

Tags: vuejs2, global, vue-component

I have create a global object in my main.js to access logged in user's data throughout the application between controllers

**main.js**

```
Vue.prototype.user = getUser() // assume a method to getUser data
```

Now the above `.user` object will be available in other components with `this.user`,

what I'm looking for is if I make change to `this.user` in any component, the changes reflects to other components too, this is not happening right now

I've two components, one to update data in `this.user` `EditProfileComponent.vue`

```
<input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" />
<input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" />
```

and other to show data `UserCardComponent.vue`

```
<h1>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}<h1>
```

on the submit of above form I'm saving data into database and getting it back at with `getUser()` on refresh,

What I'm expecting, when I make change to v-model in form it should show change directly into `UserCardComponent.vue`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you set the value of `Vue.prototype.user`, Vue is not expecting that value to be bound to the DOM, so it won't be reactive. You maybe have seen global services set up this way (like `Vue.prototype.$http` or similar), but these objects are not being bound directly to the DOM.

The most straight-forward way to maintain a reactive globally-accessible object is to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).

You can create a store to contain the `user` object:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { user: getUser() }
})
```

And register the store by passing the `store` object to the root Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

Then, in whichever components you need to access the `user` object, you can define a computed `user` property via the `Vuex.mapState` help function:

```
computed: Vuex.mapState(['user'])
```

Here's a simple example:

```js
function getUser() {
  return {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { user: getUser() },
})

Vue.component('user-card', {
  template: `<h1>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h1>`,
  computed: Vuex.mapState(['user'])
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: Vuex.mapState(['user'])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <user-card></user-card>
  <input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" />
  <input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" />
</div>
```

---

If you don't want to have to add the Vuex library, (and you really don't mind each of your components having access to the `user` object) you could also use a mixin:

```
let user = getUser();
Vue.mixin({ 
  data() { 
    return { user }
  }
})
```

This way, all of your Vue instances will have access to a reactive `user` object pointing to the `user` object initially set in you `main.js` file.

Here's an example of that:

```js
function getUser() {
  return {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  }
}

let user = getUser();
Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return { user }
  }
})

Vue.component('user-card', {
  template: `<h1>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h1>`,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <user-card></user-card>
  <input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" />
  <input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

- **Globale OBJ** >> `Vue.prototype.OBJ`
- **Reactive OBJ** >> `Vue.observable(OBJ)`
- assuming that `getUser()` return an object >>
  `Vue.prototype.user = Vue.observable( getUser() )`

Comment: Can you clarify why you came to the conclusion that the solution was to wrap the `getUser()` call in `Vue.observable()`?

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does, and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: for vue to make an object available for all components , wehave to make it globale, so we use vue.prototype for that purpose,to make it reactive to components changewe have to setit observable,