# Change Vue prototype variable in all components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm wanting to change the global variable below throughout the page

```
Vue.prototype.$color = 'green';
```

I tried using the code below but it only changes within the component I created

```
watch: {
   cor(newValue, oldVlue) {
       this.$color = newValue;
   }
}
```

is it possible for me to create a way to change the prototype variable across all components of the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs2 update Vue.prototype global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050762/vuejs2-update-vue-prototype-global-object)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To have `$color` globally available, you can use a [**Mixin**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), more specifically a [**Global Mixin**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin).

If you would only want it to be read-only, it is simplest solution (less code). See snippet:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  created: function () {
    this.$color = 'green';
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('$color #app1:', this.$color);
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('$color #app2:', this.$color);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <p>app1: {{ message }}</p>
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <p>app2: {{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

## Making `$color` reactive

To mave Vue react everywhere to changes to `$color`, you could use a **Vuex store** ([see other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257871/1850609)).

But if you **don't want** to use Vuex just for that, another possibility is to create a *Vue instance* just to hold the "shared" data. After that, create a mixin with a **computed** property that references the `$data` of this "shared" Vue instance. See demo below.

```js
// not using a Vuex store, but a separated Vue instance to hold the data
// only use this if you REALLY don't want to use Vuex, because Vuex is preferrable
let globalData = new Vue({
  data: { $color: 'green' }
});
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    $color: {
      get: function () { return globalData.$data.$color },
      set: function (newColor) { globalData.$data.$color = newColor; }
    }
  }
})

// this.$color will be available in all Vue instances...
new Vue({
  el: '#app1'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app2'
})
// ...and components
Vue.component('my-comp', {template: '#t3'});
new Vue({
  el: '#app3',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app1">Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'red'">change to red</button></div>
<div id="app2">Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'yellow'">change to yellow</button></div>

<template id="t3">
  <div>Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'purple'">change to purple</button></div>
</template>
<div id="app3"><my-comp></my-comp></div>
```

For completeness, check below to see how using **Vuex and Mixin** would be (more details on how to use Vuex [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257871/1850609)).

```js
// Using a Vuex to hold the "shared" data
// The store is not added to any instance, it is just referenced directly in the mixin
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { $color: 'green' },
  mutations: { update$color: function(state, newColor) { state.$color = newColor; } }
});
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    $color: {
      get: function() { return store.state.$color },
      set: function(newColor) { return store.commit('update$color', newColor); }
    }
  }
})


// this.$color will be available in all Vue instances...
new Vue({
  el: '#app1'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app2'
})
// ...and components
Vue.component('my-comp', {template: '#t3'});
new Vue({
  el: '#app3',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app1">Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'red'">change to red</button></div>
<div id="app2">Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'yellow'">change to yellow</button></div>

<template id="t3">
  <div>Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'purple'">change to purple</button></div>
</template>
<div id="app3"><my-comp></my-comp></div>
```

Comment: I didn't like  Vuex much, so I used MiniMongo from #Meteor with Mixin but I had to find a Vue native way as an alternative thank you.

Comment: Mixins are pretty complex and can slow Vue down, isn't there any other way to do this? How does Vuex do it?

Comment: This solution works well as if **mutable instance property**. Thank you for your showing good solution!

Comment: @NickSteele I reckon this is a bit late, but the vuex solution is [in other answer to this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257871/1850609).

Answer (score 13):

If you want a reactive global variable, Mixins may not be a good idea. Because even if you are using global Mixins, Vue actually import and inject this Mixin whenever mount new components, which means every time a new variable $color created.

I believe the mutable data types (Object or Array) combined with Vue.prototype can do the trick:
In your main.js file:

```
Vue.prototype.$color = {value: "black"};
```

In your *.vue file:

```
this.$color.value = "red"
```

In another *.vue file:

```
console.log(this.$color.value); // "red"
```

Comment: For some reason this is not the case when I test it, not sure if I am doing something wrong though...

Answer (score 4):

Since you probably want `$color` to be a property that is not just available, but reactive (and the **same**) across all components, a possible solution is to use a quick/small [**Vuex store**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

There's a runnable example below. In it you'll see three **different Vue instances** that will react to the same `$color` variable (that is at the Vuex store).

All three examples are functionally identical. I wrote them differently just to portrait different ways of using the API. Use what seems more intuitive for you.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    $color: 'green'
  },
  mutations: {
    update$color: function(state, newColor) { state.$color = newColor; }
  }
});

new Vue({
  store: store, // add this so the store is available
  el: '#app1',
  // explicitly via this.$store
  computed: {
    $color: function() { return this.$store.state.$color }
  },
  methods: {
    update$color: function(newColor) { return this.$store.commit('update$color', newColor); }
  }
})
new Vue({
  store, // shorthand for store: store
  el: '#app2',
  // using helpers mapState and mapMutations
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['$color'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(['update$color'])
  },
})
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app3',
  // using computed properties, only
  computed: {
    $color: {
      get: Vuex.mapState(['$color']).$color,
      set: Vuex.mapMutations(['update$color']).update$color
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app1">
  Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="update$color('blue')">change to blue</button> (explicitly via this.$store)
</div>
<div id="app2">
  Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="update$color('red')">change to red</button> (using helpers mapState and mapMutations)
</div>
<div id="app3">
  Color: {{ $color }} <button @click="$color = 'orange'">change to orange</button> (using computed properties, only)
</div>
```

Comment: A more simple approach to your solution would be to just use the computed $color with a getter and setter. Then j you would just do let color = this.$color and this.$color = 'red'. With this approach to don't need updateColor method, because the setter will set the Vuex $color.

Comment: @Culda-DaisaAndrei see in the example the third Vue instance (look for `#app3`).

Answer (score 4):

If you want a global reactive variable, you can use [this.$root](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance) inside child components. There is an example in vuejs docs:

```js
// The root Vue instance
new Vue({
  data: {
    foo: 1
  },
  computed: {
    bar: function () { /* ... */ }
  },
  methods: {
    baz: function () { /* ... */ }
  }
})
```

```js
// Get root data
this.$root.foo

// Set root data
this.$root.foo = 2

// Access root computed properties
this.$root.bar

// Call root methods
this.$root.baz()
```

But consider using Vuex in most cases as official docs recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the component as well

`Vue.prototype.$color= 'colorName'`

It worked for me.