# What are the performance implications of globally accessible variables in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue, globally-accessible variables do not seem to be the norm. So far, I've found 3 methods to share data between components. In my case, these variables need to be both read and write.

1. Using Vue instance properties *with mutable types*.

```js
Vue.prototype.$potato = { a: null }
```

```js
this.$potato.a = "potato!";
```

2. Creating a new Vue instance as a global mixin to store all the data.

```js
let globalData = new Vue({
  data: { $potato: null }
});

Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    $potato: {
      get: function () { return globalData.$data.$potato },
      set: function (newPotato) { globalData.$data.$potato = newPotato; }
    }
  }
});
```

```js
this.$potato = "potato!";
```

3. Using a custom EventBus, by emitting and listening for custom events.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

```js
import EventBus from './EventBus'

EventBus.$emit('_data', payload)
EventBus.$on('_data', () => {})
```

**a. What is the most proper and elegant way to achieve this?**
**b. What are the performance implications for the above (i.e., which is most efficient)?**

I personally like using the first method the most due to its' sheer simplicity. *However, instance properties are immutable.* **This makes me question if using a mutable type (such as an object or array) for the instance property is not something that should be done.**

Comment: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: I've read up about Vuex earlier, but I've felt that it was too complex for my requirements.

Comment: Vuex is the standard for state management among Vue components.  I can't say whether your app needs it or not but it's not very complex.  It's also the most elegant and proper, in answer to your question "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mixins or globals** - in my experience has no noticeable performance difference.

**About elegance** - mixins are just not very elegant, as well as global. Also, globals are not reactive by default.

If you want to avoid using Vuex - I'd recommend moving all your global data to a separated singleton like this:

`my_global.js`

```
export default {
  doStuff: function (a,b) { /* do something */ }
  state: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
}
```

And using it like:

`my-component.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>{{ state }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import GLOB from 'my-global.js'
export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data () { 
    return { state: GLOB.state }
  }
}
</script>
```

You can also move some global methods to operate with your global data, or just change it in place. Once you used any object inside component `data()` - it becomes reactive for all the components where it used.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Vue.prototype.$xxx` is useful for a few read-only injections like global variables.

I have never seen the mixin method you're proposing and it looks very weird, not to mention that mixins should be avoided when possible due to the complex and inelegant way they are to share logic.

Same for the event bus, I've seen it used a few times but it's only useful when there is not a lot of communication, it does not scale well, and it is not officially recommended. It's a hack.

You're probably looking for [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), the official global state manager for Vue. I highly recommend this library as it is both very simple, and very powerfully integrated in Vue & hooks up without caveats with all the Vue update.

Comment: I found the mixin method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261768/14632459), shared by a fellow stack-overflower. 

I've read about Vuex, but remain skeptical about the need for an additional library. Like you said, these variables that I use are quite few, and thus I can't justify using Vuex for this purpose.

Comment: How about simply using global variables, eg `window.x = 'x'`, or exporting constants in an es module?